# Use of _self attribute from Vue vm is reliable?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I need pass the main component to a deeper child. Currently I am doing on child `this.$parent.$parent`, but is not reliable for me, because this same child could be in a third+ deepth level.

My idea is transfer the main component reference between childs, like:

```
<v-some-child :main-component="_self"></v-some-child>
```

So I can use the main component instance where I think need by passing the `_self` or `this.mainComponent` data to a more inner child.

My doubt is:

1. `_self` attribute is reliable to points to component Vue instance? Seems that `_` prefix is to internal attributes, and `$` for public (reliable). If it is true, what I can do use?
2. There are some better way to do what I wants?

Thanks!

---

**Edit 1:** as an immediate more reliable workaround, I am using `data() { self: this }`, then I am using `:main-component="self"`.

Comment: If your state is that complex, perhaps it makes sense to use some state management patterns - either VueX or [Event Bus](https://medium.com/@andrejsabrickis/https-medium-com-andrejsabrickis-create-simple-eventbus-to-communicate-between-vue-js-components-cdc11cd59860)? What exactly should be passed to descendants?

Comment: what does **main component** means? is it topest-level component? if so, uses `this.$root` in your deeper child component. If directly pass component instance as prop, probably may meet reactivity issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm unclear where _self is getting set in your case.  Typically `_self = this;` is an approach used by developers to pass the the current Vue instance via closure to a callback function.  I wouldn't trust a `_self` unless I knew exactly where it was getting set.

Your edit1 should absolutely work.  As long as `data(){ self: this }` is happening on the main Vue instance and in the components you use `self` when setting a property via a `:` like `:main-component="self"` then that should work fine given that the main Vue component data properties are merged into all components used by that vue instance.
It's kinda a cleaver approach frankly.  As @raina77ow mentioned it may make sense to look at VueX or an EventBus but the approach you propose in Edit1 should be a reliable way to pass around the main Vue instance.

As an aside, I wonder if `root` or `main` might be a better name then self.  Given that it's the "self"  of the main or root level Vue instance not the the "self" of the child passing the value.

Comment: `main` is just for example. In my context I call it `builder` (then I have some children live `builder > builder-section > builder-column > { builder-component or builder-section }`). So `builder-section` need access `builder` independent if is the direct or indirect child. But thanks for clarification. I have used `data()` solution and it works perfectly!